# What is the potential danger of riding bicycle with cracked chainstay and how to fix it?

Tags: frames, repair

[image]

I got a bicycle that has this big tear in the chainstay.

Is it safe for city riding? What is the potential danger?

What could someone have done to cause this kind of damage?

Most importantly what is a good procedure and material to use to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: If you mean you recently purchased this from someone, they may have knowingly sold you an unsafe bicycle. You nay be able to get the =m to take it back and refund you your money.

Comment: Is the frame aluminum or steel?  It may have been damaged by a kinked chain or by something getting caught between frame and hub.  Or possibly from an exceptionally hard landing from a jump.  It's impossible to tell if a (reasonably) safe repair is possible without viewing it first-hand.  Certainly a frame guy could fix it, but that would be expensive.

Comment: If you're the original owner, it may be worth checking your options at https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/trek_bikes_warranty/   If you just bought it, you were sold a lemon.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks according to the website it's body using aluminum

Comment: @Ezeewei you're in danger of falling into the "good money after bad" fallacy.  You're considering throwing more money at a bad purchase to try and recover something from this lemon.  Better to dump it and learn your lesson.

Comment: @Criggie yea, haha, I am a person hates to give up and accept failure many times. Well, I guess its a lesson learned, not very expensive lesson is a good thing. and most of its part are pretty solid still. Thanks man

Comment: If it was my bike, I *might* consider (after inspecting it first hand and if I knew what caused the crack) wrapping a piece of sheet steel around the stay and securing it with a couple of spiral hose clamps.  Put some epoxy on before wrapping.  But I certainly would not advocate that just based on the sparse info available here.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I actually like that idea, even though I do not know most of the items you just mentioned ha

Comment: I had a frame crack on the chainstay just behind the bottom bracket (hidden between the chainring and the tyre). The chainstay was completely cracked through, but the only noticeable effect was that it made a heap of noise (I thought it was the BB) and the rear derailuer was ghost shifting like crazy because the cable spanned the crack which would widen and shorten as I pedalled. I replaced the frame as soon as I saw it, but it wasn't like the bike suddenly collapsed.

Answer (score 11):

The frame isn’t safe for using anywhere.

The potential danger is that the stay will break most likely locking up the back wheel. It might be merely inconvenient or it might be fatal taken in combination with speed or traffic.

A possible reason for the crack is inappropriate use of the frame e.g jumps, crash damage or it might just be an old cheap Walmart frame which has fatigued.

The frame seems to be alloy from the lack of rust in the fracture. It can’t be fixed within the scope of the bikes probable value. The presence of V brakes and a stamped metal derailleur indicates a low end bike.

Salvage parts if you want and transfer to a not broken frame or just purchase a whole new one. The cost balance on that task will depend on whether you have bike fixing skills and tools or whether you need to take it to a bike shop.

Seriously, don’t use this bike as it is right now.

Comment: its a Trek 4100 how much usually this kind of fix will cost? If I really want to get it fixed?

Comment: Let it go. It was a $300 new bike in 2003. You can’t repair alloy frames. Sorry.

Comment: @Ezeewei Repairing this kind of frame is theoretically possible, but it's virtually never done because it would require stripping the bike down, having a skilled bike framebuilder replace the tube, getting the frame re-heat-treated, repainted/coated, and then built back up. That's what it takes to do right and none of those steps can really be skipped, and it will cost far more than the bike is worth. Note it is possible to do it not right in any number of ways, i.e. have someone with a TIG welder go to town on it and never mind the heat treatment, but it probably won't end well.

Comment: @NathanKnutson what if I just pretty much use a piece of ... alumnimum and weld it onto the broken area? that's bad?

Comment: @Ezeewei Have you welded aluminum before?

Comment: Welding aluminium is 10x harder than welding steel.   Plus it could easily be a 7005 aluminium alloy which is pre-heat treated, so heating it again will destroy the tempering and make it more brittle or more soft, (can't remember which way it goes sorry.)    Either way, the frame becomes even more dangerous "repaired"

Comment: @Criggie lol thanks man, that's the knowledge field I have no idea about... still learning! kinda fun!

Comment: @Paparazzi nop, has no idea, just saw a youtube video on welding two aluminum piece together, and doesn't seems very hard, so I thought I'd try at least ha

Comment: @Ezeewei Well, if you want to learn how to weld aluminium, you now have a big lump of the stuff to practise on! But please promise you won't ever use the result as a bike.

Answer (score 7):

The potential danger is **your death** should the chainstay part at while being ridden, leaving you on an uncontrollable bike.

Calling it bluntly, you'd be foolhardy to ride a bike that you know is not structurally sound.

Salvage any good parts off it and junk the frame.  You only get one life.

Answer (score -1):

It's never a reasonable idea to ride a broken frame!
Although in this case maybe it's not too bad. Since the crack is for sure not arose from the stress due to riding. The force will act in the direction of the chainstay and there you might still have enough strength. 
If you really want to take the risk, try gluing it with epoxy-metal I had good results with that.

BUT STILL, it will never be a save bike anymore and you should never think about selling it or so.

Comment: As you say, repairs won't be safe, so suggesting repairing it doesn't seem appropriate.

Comment: I repaired a broken frame and a break lever with epoxy-metal just by curiosity. By my surprise it worked.
I mentioned multiple times that you should be aware and that it will never be save again.  But I think it's okay to give a suggestion how it could work. or is it a common rule not to answer if it could be dangerous?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a site rule or policy against suggesting dangerous things. My own feeling is that good answers shouldn't do that but other people may very well disagree. You could ask on [meta].